# I am trying to connect and read data from mysql in node js and react project with clinet and server setup but

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

**I am trying to connect and read data from MySQL database in node js and react project with client and server setup but unable to get success, here is the code, thanks to all those who can help me, I am a new learner

**this is index.js source code for server-side****

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createPool({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '3Nbnv21PP',
   database: 'cpdb',
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api/fetch', (req, res) => {
  const sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM cpdb.schools';
  db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => { res.send(result); });
});
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Running on port 3001');
});
```

---

### on server-side I am getting this error : (index):6772 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

**this is the app.js source code for client-side**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css'

function App () {
  const [schlist, setschlist] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/fetch').then((response) => {
      setschlist(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>HEllO</h1>
      
      {schlist.map((val, index) => {
        return <h1 key={index.id}> Sch: {val.schoolName} | Stu: {val.toatlStudents} | TTeach: {val.totalTeachers} | TFees: {val.TotalFeesCollected} </h1>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

---

### on client-side I am getting this

[click on this image to see console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qf5a.png)

**Here is the link to my GitHub repository**

https://github.com/CodePex/db-test.git

Comment: No, there is no sign of any response, is there any other way to check for it?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Here was the error, i forgot to place parentheses after express.json

app.use(express.json());